# Integral with help of fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

When I solve problems like this

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\int_{x}^{x^2}\ln^3 t\,dt
$$

I usually would set $$ F(x)=\int_{0}^{x^2}\ln^3 t\,dt $$

and then with help of the fundamental theorem of calculus I would get:

$$
\int_{x}^{x^2}\ln^3 t\,dt=F(x^2)-F(x)
$$

and then apply chain rule:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\int_{x}^{x^2}\ln^3 t\,dt= \cdots = \frac{6\ln^2 x^2}{x}-\frac{3\ln^2 x}{x}
$$

but in this case I get discontinuity at x = 0 and I guess that makes my solution invalid. I dont know how to tackle this problem so I appreciate all help I can get.

Comment: Choose any lower limit of integration you like.  It doesn't have to be $0$.

Comment: Isn't this just $2x\ln^3x^2 - \ln^3x$ via FTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points of confusion here:

- Unless the problem says differently, there's no reason for this to make sense at $x=0$.  After all, $\ln x$ doesn't!
- $F(t)$ is *not* $\ln^3 t$.  Rather, $F(t)$ is some function whose *derivative* is $F'(t) = \ln^3 t$.  IOW, Andrew Li is correct: the expression simplifies to $2x\ln^3 x^2 - \ln^3 x$.  (Which further simplifies to $(16x-1)\ln^3 x$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot... I don't know why I tried to go through 0. I believe I got myself confused when I compared solutions to my other problems.

Answer (score 2):

One part of the "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus" says that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)dt= f(x)$ where $a$ can be any number.

To deal with $\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{x^2} f(t)dt$, I would first break the integral into $\int_x^a f(t)dt+ \int_a^{x^2}dt= -\int_a^x f(t)dt+ \int)a^{x^2} f(t)t$ where, again, $a$ is any number.

Certainly, the "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\int_a^x f(t)dt\right)= -f(x)$.  For the other integral, let $u= x^2$ so that can be written as $\int_a^u f(t)dt$.  Then by the "fundamental Theorem of Calculus", together with the "chain rule" for differentiation, $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^u f(t)dt= \left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)\frac{d}{du}\int_a^u f(t)dt= \frac{du}{dx} f(u)= 2x f(x^2)$$

Putting those together, $\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{x^2} f(t)dt$$= 2xf(x^2)- f(x)$.  In this example, $f(t)= \ln^3(t)$ so that $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{x^2} \ln^3(t)dt= 2x\ln^3(x^2)- \ln^3(x)$$.